# Proof that the velocity vector is tangential to the path?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

In calculus class my teacher asserted that the velocity vector is tangential to the path a point takes. I have tried to prove this but have gotten stuck. I computed $\dfrac{v_y}{v_x}$ to be $\dfrac{{dy}/{dt}}{{dx}/{dt}}$ but haven't gotten further. What is the proof that the velocity vector is tangential to the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proof
$(dy/dt)/(dx/dt) = (dy/dt) * (dt/dx) = (dy/dx)$. The first and second equality are results from the chain rule. For the first equality, consider that $(dx/dt) * (dt/dx) = dx/dx = 1$.